# Format text in datatable c#, asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I would like to format my text to Titlecase or lowercase in the controller before viewing in Razor page. but it is not working. what I am doing wrong here. I see no effect in view.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("abc")))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("proc_Productlist", sqlConnection);
        sqlDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlDa.Fill(dataTable);

        TextInfo textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;

        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            textInfo.ToTitleCase(row["Name"].ToString().ToLower());
            textInfo.ToLower(row["Made"].ToString().ToLower());
        }
    }
    return View(dataTable);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't reassign the result of the method *ToTitleCase* or *ToLower* to **row["Name"]**.
If you read the documentation about *ToTitleCase* it says:
**Returns
The specified string converted to title case.**
You need to write:

```
row["Name"] = textInfo.ToTitleCase(row["Name"].ToString().ToLower());
row["Made"] = textInfo.ToLower(row["Made"].ToString().ToLower());
```

Have a nice day.

*Source*: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase?view=net-5.0

Comment: Makes sense, thank you for solution I totally forgot to reassign it. have a nice day